# CA certificates location in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssl, certificates, openssl, ubuntu

Can you please point to me where can I locate the CA certificates file in Ubuntu 18.04? I have a program that needs the path that point to the CAs directory for certs. validation.

Comment: This will probably help: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html.en

Comment: @Haxiel link now dead. also, question now answered. delete comment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should be `/etc/ssl/certs/` or `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html

Note this store is [not necessarily used consistently by all applications](https://superuser.com/a/719047/110495).  My guess is that command-line programs like `curl` are set up to use it.